# Multiple sizeColumnsToFit() ag-grid React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have three different ag-grid React tables in my component, with specific `gridOptions` and `columnDefs`. I want all of the three tables to auto-resize columns to fit content on window resize.

I use `onGridReady` and `sizeColumnsToFit()` functions with `setTimeout` to achieve that.
But the problem is that only the last declared `ag-grid` table auto-resizes (as if the declarations before were ignored) :

```
let gridOptions1 = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs1,

    onGridReady(params) {
      console.log(params)
      window.onresize = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }, 500);
      };
    },
    onFirstDataRendered(params) {
      params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    },
  };

let gridOptions2 = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs2,

    onGridReady(params) {
      console.log(params)
      window.onresize = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }, 500);
      };
    },
    onFirstDataRendered(params) {
      params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    },
  };

let gridOptions3 = {

    columnDefs: columnDefs3,

    onGridReady(params) {
      console.log(params)
      window.onresize = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }, 500);
      };
    },
    onFirstDataRendered(params) {
      params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    },
  };
```

In that example, the `sizeColumnsToFit()` function works for the third grid only.

Do you know how to achieve to do that for all of the tables?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to only use onFirstDataRendered functions (remove onGridReady) and pass specific keys to aggrid tables depending on width and height :

```
import React from 'react'
    
function debounce(fn, ms) {
      let timer
      return _ => {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(_ => {
          timer = null
          fn.apply(this, arguments)
        }, ms)
      };
    }
    
function MyComponent() {
      const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({ 
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth
      })
      React.useEffect(() => {
        const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
          setDimensions({
            height: window.innerHeight,
            width: window.innerWidth
          })
        }, 1000)
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize)
    
    return _ => {
          window.removeEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize)
        
    }
      })
      return <><AgGridReact
                            key={dimensions.width + dimensions.height}
                            rowData={data1}
                            gridOptions={gridOptions1}
                          ></AgGridReact>
<AgGridReact
                            key={dimensions.width + dimensions.height + "2"}
                            rowData={data2}
                            gridOptions={gridOptions2}
                          ></AgGridReact></>
    }
```